# You have requested a non-existent parameter "faker.populate.class"

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I get this error after having installed `willdurand/BazingaFakerBundle` with composer:

> ParameterNotFoundException
>   You have requested a non-existent parameter "faker.populate.class"

I have added this in my config_dev.yml file:

```
bazinga_faker:
    orm: doctrine
    locale: fr_FR
    entities:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
             number: 20
```

I'm using Symfony 3.4.

Did I forget to configure something? Thank you

EDIT: My composer.json

> ```
> "require": {
>     "php": ">=5.5.9",
>     "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
>     "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
>     "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
>     "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
>     "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
>     "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.7",
>     "lexik/form-filter-bundle": "^5.0",
>     "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
>     "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
>     "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
>     "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
>     "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
>     "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
>     "symfony/templating": "^4.0",
>     "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
>     "willdurand/faker-bundle": "^1.4"
> },
> "require-dev": {
>     "pugx/generator-bundle": "2.4.*",
>     "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
>     "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
> },
> ```

Comment: Which version specifically you did install? We don't read tea leaves here. `composer -i | grep willdurand`

Comment: Sorry, the command didn't work, but here is the version from composer.json:         "willdurand/faker-bundle": "^1.4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That bundle, as of 1.3 & also still 1.4 has an issue with a class-name parameter, as described in [issue #48](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaFakerBundle/issues/48) and [PR #49](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaFakerBundle/pull/49).

Comment: Thank you, I had to replace line 29 with         <service id="Bazinga\Bundle\FakerBundle\Command\PopulateCommand" class="%faker.populate_command.class%">

Comment: I know. I wrote the #49 PR.